# how can i get title from bs4 python, this is the instagram total number of followers

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

i am using this code to extract follower numbers

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/test/?hl=en")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
htmlcontent = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, 'html.parser')
followers = (soup.find_all('a', class_='-nal3'))
```

While i print **followers** it gives this output,
no i am not able extract **title** someone please help

```
[<a class="-nal3" href="/test/followers/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY" title="1,001,318">1m</span> followers</a>, <a class="-nal3" href="/test/following/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY">588</span> following</a>]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab the attribute from the HTML code returned by the `soup` you have to use `[]` brackets and between them enter a string which is the name of the Key which value you want to get. In your case, it will be

```
print(i['title'])
```

There is also the second method which will work like a `try` clause - it will avoid the error if the `title` is not in the element

```
print(i.get('title'))
```

Comment: You forgot to close your `[]` should be `i['title']` not `i['title'`

Comment: what is i in this `print(i['title'])`  it is giving error `   raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'i'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: @farhanAlam you have edited the post. now if you want to extract all titles just use `[x.get('title) for x in followers]` and please reaccept my answer.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw I didn't get anything from this `[x.get('title) for x in followers]` i got only in the response = `[None, None]`

Comment: try `[x['title'] for x in followers]`